# Attach Array Data to Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a product table which has column name `unit_id`, I have approximate 15 units data. And I stored a custom key of unit to the product as you can check in the screenshot.

[image]

And the Units data is stored in settings table, in a single row and meta_value holds all the units data in json format

[image]

Now the problem is I have to run two queries every time for products, need help to know more convenient.

```
// For Products
Product::where('id', 1)->first();

// For settings
Settings::where('meta_key', 'product_units')->first();
```

Is there any way so that I attach the **Settings** data in **Product** model, the problem we get for multiple products not single.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a mutator inside the Products model https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators.

```
public function getProductUnitsAttribute() {
    return Settings::where('meta_key', 'product_units')->first();
}
```

so you can do this to get the settings

```
$product = Product::where('id', 1)->first();
$product->product_units;
```

but i don't think that this is a good practice.